# After upgrade in app purchase product id is invalid

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm testing my in app purchase code for an update to my app.  The in app purchase works great when I do an install from xcode to my phone.  The issue arises when I have the currently released version installed on my phone then I install the dev version over the top of the release version.  When I install in this way my product ID comes back as invalid even though I've tested it many times and it works as long as I didn't have the release version installed previous to installing the dev version.

We did alter our Bundle ID in this update but everything has worked except when we install in the way I described above.

Has anybody encountered this behavior before?

Also the currently released version does not have in app purchases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens all the time.

If you install your development version over the App Store version - new In App Purchases IDs are returned as invalid.

This will work perfectly when you upload the new version to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My app is currently in review, I'll let you know if the in app purchase works once it's available for download.

Comment: You were right, once released into that app store the in app purchase works fine.  Kind of obnoxious for testing though.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: But if i already have an app in the AppStore, and i want to add in app purchases, how can i test it?

Comment: @Avrahamshuk, delete the app downloaded from the AppStore and then install a fresh copy of your app from development. This will work.

Comment: I tried this for dozens of times and it didn't solve it. In the end i ended up formatting the ipad and restoring it to factory version and it did work. Apparently JailBreak is messing up the device... :-)